# Is there other option than a Chinook to transport 2 cars simultaneously?

Tags: helicopter, cargo

If a civilian wants to fly between homes several hundred miles apart AND carry 2 cars with him what are the options other than a chinook?

Comment: First, does it have to be a helicopter? Second, is there some reason you can't just keep spare cars at the hangar on the other end?

Comment: Are we talking a couple Humvees, or Smart FourTwos? If you can afford the helicopter, having spare cars shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Also, let me be the first to say: If you are someone who’s genuinely capable of considering a private Chinook to transport vehicles back and forth between your 2 homes, I’d like to officially offer my services as a pilot. I’m a helicopter pilot with multiple airplane ratings as well. I’ll even long line your cars directly onto your driveway, 

Comment: Another alternative: pay two drivers to take the cars while you fly. Make sure to have one car leave early so you have something to drive at the other side

Comment: Nice problem to have :D

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you really trying to solve, or is this just speculative?

Comment: Yeah, depending on the cars, it’s gotta be WAY cheaper to buy a few spare vehicles and go with a smaller helicopter.  Of course that might not impress the neighbors as much, in case that’s your goal...  :)

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for the link to the XY problem!  Brilliant, and applicable so often and in so many ways.  Definitely in this case.  At work my first step was always to come up with a clear problem statement.  I.e. “the goal is ___, the challenge is ___, it’s a problem because ___, the options are ___.”  Just taking the time to do this can sometimes produce the clarity needed for an obvious solution will pop out.

Comment: I think you should precise what kind of cars you want to transport. Transporting 2 vans is not the same as transporting 2 [smarts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Fortwo)

Comment: @MichaelHall: In programming, there is the practice of *rubber ducking*, which is literally just explaining the problem to a rubber duck sitting on your monitor. (You can tell this practice is older than flatscreens :-D ) There's also a famous story of a professor who instituted a rule that you could come to him at *any time* with a problem, provided you explained the problem to his assistant first, and the assistant couldn't solve it. The number of students disturbing him dropped dramatically, since it turns out most problems were solved by the assistant.

Comment: The twist: the assistant was a teddy bear. The "Stack Exchange Effect", where you compose a question only to delete it before posting because you found the answer is also related.

Comment: Manu H may have been alluding to this, but to any prospective Chinook buyers out there:  CHECK THAT YOUR CARS WILL FIT.  It's really more of a medium-lift helicopter than heavy-lift.

Comment: @Kevin Duffield, well... did you find a useful answer here?

Answer (score 5):

You could use an [Mi-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26) to transport your two cars, as seen here:

[image: A pair of BMD-2s rolls off an Mi-26; image from rusarmy.com]

With a payload of up to 20 tons, it should be able to lift many useful combinations of two vehicles.

Comment: Yep.  Accept this answer and go buy one now.  Problem solved.  See how helpful we are here?

Comment: Sorry. I’m not laughing at this. It’s something else... 

Comment: NIce cars there.

Answer (score 5):

[Top Gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear_(2002_TV_series)) demonstrated that 3 cars fit comfortably in an [Ilyushin Il-76](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-76). And that it [can be hired](https://www.aircharternetwork.com.au/cargo-aircraft/ilyushin-il-76/).

[image]

[image]

You can back right into the cargo hold up the loading ramp, and drive right back out again when you get to your destination.

[image]

Designed to operate from unimproved (unpaved) strips and with a 1,500 foot landing roll capability (using thrust reversers), it's the clear and proven choice for your civilian car transportation needs.

Comment: No go. The OP wants to transport 2 cars, not 3.

Comment: Can't he buy a third car and leave it in the Ilyushin?

Comment: @RainerP. But then they have to decide which car to buy third. Imagine how long that can take. First they'll have to create an account on the Mv SE...

Comment: But the OP may not have a 1500 ft strip at one of his houses.  For instance, I think there are houses built on private inholdings within national parks & monuments.

Comment: @jamesqf Admittedly this is indeed an impractical answer to an impractical question. But that was precisely Top Gear's forté and I couldn't resist :)

Comment: Also, although you may get the Il-76 down in 1,500', you certainly won't get it back up again, at least without JATO (which I don't believe the Il-76 was designed for).

Comment: @Therac I thought it was a fantastic answer that focused on the exacting requirements of the original specification. Why spend more jet fuel than you need to? lol

Comment: In all seriousness though, I believe OP intended to request a chopper rather than a fixed wing.